# Rails search in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I have a situation where I would like a user to be able to select another user as part of a form.

I have similar things working in my app using the 'bootstrap-multiselect-rails4' gem but I don't need the multiselect aspect and that relies on loading all of the options into a select tag which could be vast with all users in it.

I guess ideally it would be a text box which you type in and it searches the users and returns a list of matching users from which you can select one, all without leaving that page.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: might want to take a look at bootstrap typeahead @ https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-typeahead-rails

Comment: also this one https://github.com/rayasocialmedia/rails_autocomplete

Comment: Great. That second one looks simpler and possibly better for my needs. I will try it out.